# Why is C++11 std::array a struct rather than a class?

Tags: c++11, stdarray

Out of curiosity, I had a look at the LLVM implementation of std::array, and noticed that it is a struct. Most other STL containers I've looked at (vector, queue, map) are classes. And it appears in the standard as a struct so is intentional.

Anyone know why this might be?

Comment: It appears to be a frequently applied convention to make POD types structs, although I don't know if that is the reason here.

Comment: aggregates may not have private nor protected members, and `std::array` is required to be an aggregate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically, it's neither a struct nor a class -- it's a template.

`std::array` is required to be an `aggregate`. To make a long story short, this ends up meaning that it can't have anything private -- so it might as well be written as a `struct` (which defaults to making everything public) instead of a `class`, (which defaults to making everything private).

If you wanted to you could write it as a `class` anyway:

```
template <...>
class array {
public:
// ...
```

But you need to make everything public anyway, so you might as well use a `struct` that does that by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know why the decision was made to make std::array an aggregate?

Comment: @elSnape `std::array` is older than C++11 (boost, C++03TR1), and required aggregate-initialization syntax in C++03 for things like `std::array<int, 5> my_arr = {1,2,3,4,5};`

Comment: @elSnape Because std::array needs to be as thin as possible.  A design decision is that all of std::array's code should disappear at compile time, to make it just as efficient (space and time) as a naked array.

Answer (score 1):

`std::array` is a POD type so that it can be initialized like this:

```
std::array<int, 5> arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

This is different from the initialization from a `initializer_list` in that the array does not actually allocate new space for the array elements and moves the data from the initializer list in there, but the data in the brackets (that ends up in the initialized data segment) ***is*** the internal representation of the array.

This means that there is no copying or moving, in fact there is no code running to initialize anything. The array is ready to go as soon as your executable is loaded into memory.

Comment: A variadic template constructor could have the same syntax, and move elision (+ optimizations) should result in the same speed.

Comment: @DyP No, because that would still require code to run. For the `std::array` *there is no code doing any initialization in run-time*. Zero. Remember my other post you commented on? "No code" is as fast as you get.

Comment: @DyP Also, this solves some other problems like the undefined order of initialization and destruction of global static objects. This simply does not apply to `std::array`s of simple types. They come pre-initalized and exist till the OS frees the proces's memory, just like C-style arrays.

Comment: There's no guarantee static non-constexpr objects will be initialized during static initialization. Aggregate-initialization is specified as copy-initialization of the members of the aggregate. Also, [a quick test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/978326404a954bcf) with g++4.8.1 at -O3 shows no difference between the assembly output of `std::array` vs a similar non-aggregate type with said template ctor.

Comment: @DyP 3.8 "Object lifetime" p1 guarantees the lifetime for POD types wit no non-trivial initialization to be as soon as "storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained". P2 extends that to arrays. Any initialized POD type, const or not, is placed in the "initialized data" section.

Comment: POD <-> aggregate. They're not the same. In fact, `std::array<std::string>` is not a POD, but an aggregate.

Comment: @DyP If GCC executes any code to initialize an `std::array` then it sucks. If it does not execute any code for initializing the "similar non-aggregate" then I'm pretty sure it breaks the standard somewhere, as it needs to execute the "non-trivial constructor".

Comment: Only under the as-if rule. And as my templated ctor doesn't have any observable behaviour (other than initializing), I'm pretty sure it doesn't violate any rule.

Comment: @DyP The rules we are talking about apply for both. Did you read the sections in the standard I'm referring to? Sorry, but I'm losing interest in this discussion.

Comment: 3.8 doesn't include fundamental types, however it states that trivial copy/move construction is non-trivial initialization. Therefore I think it applies as well to aggregate-initialization even if the aggregate members are fundamental types (non-trivial init). It is clear that the *lifetime of an object* doesn't refer to its storage duration (but only to the guarantees of when you can use it w/o UB). Even if this explicitly allows putting `std::array`s into the initialized data section, it doesn't forbid doing so with other objects as well.

Comment: "If GCC executes any code to initialize an std::array then it sucks." I've now looked into the assembly, and it seems as if gcc does execute code if the array is a local variable to `main`, but not if it's defined at global scope. The *same* happens for my `non_aggr` type, if I make the ctor `constexpr`. If it isn't `constexpr`, it indeed executes code to initialize my `non_aggr` type.

Comment: @DyP 3.8 p1 states: "The lifetime of an object of type T begins when: — storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and — if the object has non-trivial initialization, its initialization is complete." Aggregate initialization is trivial. It is not a copy or move initialization. Therefore the second case does not apply. This makes sense because it is the goal of these rules to allow aggregate initialization with no run-time cost.

Comment: @DyP I did not expect GCC to execute code to initialize a global static std::array, because it's not required to by the standard. This is what I'm trying to explain to you all the time. GCC still needs to allocate and initialize the stack space for it, that's normal. But again, I really don't see where this discussion is going. I really wished you would not misuse this as a way to learn about these things. Why don't you open a new question instead?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38619/discussion-between-dyp-and-fozi)